# Write sequence of character not as string as value in dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have an interesting problem.
I am creating a `dictionary` in a for loop which I finally want to save a `.js` file. I need this file for another task in `javascript`. I want to dynamically add the elements of the `list` as `keys` to the `dictionary`. As `values` I want to compose a `function`, which is not saved as `string` within the `dictionary`. I must not be saved as a `string`, otherwise `javascript` is not able to interpret it as a function.

```
import json
someList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
newDict = {}
for letter in someList:
    newDict[letter] = f"require('some/path/{letter}')"

with open("newFile.json", "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(newDict))
```

When I now have a look at the `.json` file, I get this

```
{
    "a": "require('some/path/a')",
    "b": "require('some/path/b')",
    "c": "require('some/path/c')",
    "d": "require('some/path/d')",
}
```

However, what I need is this (no quotation marks around the `value` of the `key`

```
{
    "a": require('some/path/a'),
    "b": require('some/path/b'),
    "c": require('some/path/c'),
    "d": require('some/path/d'),
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I am not sure if `json.dumps()` is the proper function here. However, `JavaScript Objects` and `JSON` have a lot in common: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: That is just the definition of JSON. A string is enclosed in doule quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
someList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
newDict = "{\n"
for letter in someList:
    newDict += f'\t"{letter}": require(\'some/path/{letter}\'),\n'
newDict += "}"

with open("newFile.json", "w") as file:
    file.write(newDict)
```

This is what you will get in the `.json` file

```sh
{
    "a": require('some/path/a'),
    "b": require('some/path/b'),
    "c": require('some/path/c'),
    "d": require('some/path/d'),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the definition of the [`JSON Spec`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.

---

Note that in `python` code that is same, a string is enclosed in simple or double quotes

---

Without the quotes, it would be impossible to parse it, no quotes means a numerical value. If you try to parse and print it, you'll see no problem

```
import json

x = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 10}
print(x)  # {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 10}
x = json.dumps(x)
print(x)  # {"k1": "v1", "k2": 10}
x = json.loads(x)
print(x)  # {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 1O}
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But I actually need that to be not a string. It is actually a function I am writing and then saving it to a `.js` file which I am using in `javascript` finally. I am only preparing some data in Python. That is why I need this to be not a string, so that `javascript` interprets it as a function.

Comment: @Stophface that is **very** unclear. JSON is a very good format as it normalized. In you initial post you didn't talk about "interpret it as a function" I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: I edited my Q accordingly. Maybe it is more clear now.

Comment: @Stophface writing non-json content in a JSON file, that is the problem